# Spring Web MVC can not access jsp files in intellij

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets, intellij-idea

I have configured a spring web MVC project in INTELLIJ ide .The tutorial i followed said localhost:8080/dispatcher/hello will show the hello.jsp.But in the browser i found "file not found". I have checked plenty of similar question but none worked for me.After startup server shows index.jsp and server is tomat.
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bvlyb.png)

HelloController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
        return "hello";
    }

}
```

ApplicationContext

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorialspoint" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

dispatchet-servlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Artifacts

```
<component name="ArtifactManager">
  <artifact type="exploded-war" name="SpringWeb:war exploded">
    <output-path>$PROJECT_DIR$/out/artifacts/SpringWeb_war_exploded</output-path>
    <root id="root">
      <element id="javaee-facet-resources" facet="SpringWeb/web/Web" />
      <element id="directory" name="WEB-INF">
        <element id="directory" name="classes">
          <element id="module-output" name="SpringWeb" />
        </element>
        <element id="directory" name="lib">
          <element id="library" level="application" name="Spring MVC-4.3.7.RELEASE" />
          <element id="library" level="project" name="Spring-4.3.7.RELEASE" />
        </element>
      </element>
    </root>
  </artifact>
</component>
```

Comment: I don't see how `dispatcher/hello` would map to `WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp` with your configuration. Could you please describe which configuration options would do such a mapping?

Comment: Without analysing the other configs (and assuming they work) the controller should map to `/hello` instead of `/dispatcher/hello/` if your run configuration maps the artifact to `/`

Comment: I am newbie.Can you recommend what should be the url or by what change i can access those jsp files.

Answer (score 0):

I think..

How would you change  lines

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

if you want to use  like "*.jsp",
you should using `<jsp-config>` or... your WAS container setting.
(Because, if you type `<servlet-mapping>` in Webapp,WAS container's setting will be ignored)